Descriptor set in Vulkan using the same binding for different resource types
I have a shader that uses constant buffer, image and sampler all bound as the first slot (0). If I try to create a descriptor set layout with binding == 0 for multiple entries I get a validation error:
validation layer: Validation Error: [ VUID-VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo-binding-00279 ] | MessageID = 0xf6f49662 | vkCreateDescriptorSetLayout(): pCreateInfo->pBindings[1].binding is duplicated at pBindings[0].binding.

The Vulkan spec states:

If the perStageDescriptorSet feature is not enabled, or flags does not contain VK_DESCRIPTOR_SET_LAYOUT_CREATE_PER_STAGE_BIT_NV, then the VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::binding members of the elements of the pBindings array must each have different values

Is there a way to fix this without using the NV extension? (I'm working with AMD card)
Expecting to define a descriptor set layout where multiple resource types are used at the first slot.


Expecting to define a descriptor set layout where multiple resource types are used at the first slot.

Aliasing the same descriptor set for multiple resource type bindings in the shader is possible, but it's not supported by default. You will need to enable sparse binding (if the target supports it).
VkPhysicalDeviceDescriptorIndexingFeatures.descriptorBindingPartiallyBound = VK_TRUE;

I am coming from d3d12/hlsl where each resource type has its own index. In fact I can straigh compile the hlsl shader without errors in glsl:
Texture2DArray Tex : register(t0);
sampler Sampler : register(s0);
Isn't this index (0) the binding ?

Updated the answer - "first slot" in your question was somewhat ambiguous given you have two IDs  here (set and location). You can alias sets for different resource types.
